# Не сохраняется COOKIE

Tags: php

Код на одной странице:

```
if ($row['password'] == $pass) {
    setcookie("login", $login, time()+9999999);
    echo $_COOKIE['login'];
}
```

`echo` выводит пустую строку. 
На локальном сервере все работало корректно

Comment: а в `if` вообще попадает?  а страницу перезагружали? а что будет если дополнить еще путь, на который распространяется (4 параметр), хотя бы слеш?

Comment: В if попадает, перезагружал, ничего не меняется

Comment: domain не выставили в setcookie. да и path не помешает. Но без domain точно не взлетит

Comment: `setcookie("login", $_COOKIE['login'] =  $login, time()+9999999);` хак

Comment: а путь? что с путем (4 параметром)?

Comment: оставь дефолтным, после перезагрузки страницы пишутся данные в кукисы?

Comment: нет, не пишутся

Comment: путь добавлял, ничего не изменилось

Comment: забыл указать что на локальном сервере все работало

Comment: попробуйте время меньше указать...хотя бы 9999...... и еще кодировка файла какая? `utf8 без bom`?........а может на хосте отключены куки) посмотри там.....в поддержку напиши... phpinfo посмотри........ ошибки включи и посмотри - может ошибки выводит

Comment: сначала я указывал время 3600, uft8 без bom. Буду общаться с поддрежкой

Answer (score 2):

Значение появится в массиве `$_COOKIE` только после перезагрузки страницы, так как `setcookie` только задает значение, которое должно быть передано клиенту.

Comment: после перехода на другую страницу значение куки пустое

Comment: Попробуйте 
`setcookie("login", $login, time()+9999999, '/', 'youdomainname');`
Так же посмотрите какой результат возвращает setcookie,
если возвращает false - большая вероятность того, что перед установкой куки уже был вывод на клиент